# I have multiple flask microservices that all communicate with each other, how would I configure docker?

Tags: python, docker, flask, dockerfile, microservices

I have multiple flask microservices (this is obviously obfuscated to protect IP)

```
├── README.md
├── api_starter.py
├── app_api.py
├── service1
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── api.py
│   └── service1.py
├── service2
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── api.py
│   ├── service2.py
├── dags
│   ├── airflow_pipeline_runner.py
├── service3
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── api.py
│   ├── service3.py
├── service4
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── api.py
│   └── service4.py
├── service5
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── api.py
│   └── service5.py
├── service6
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── api.py
│   └── service6.py
├── requirements.txt
└── service7
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── api.py
    └── service7.py
```

Each one of these microservices are being run by the api_starter. Each of these microservices communicate with each other. What's the best way to dockerize this application? Do I give each microservice a docker file and then have a docker-compose.yml in the root of the directory? Each of these microservices communicate with each other. Any and all

Comment: Are these services importing each other or are they communicating over tcp ports?

Comment: currently communicating through an airflow pipeline which is basically just using http requests (tcp is better though)

Comment: It's hard to help without more information, really. Yes, each will need a Dockerfile and EXPOSE the appropriate ports. Or you can use one Dockerfile, expose all the ports and just RUN the respective services via the `python` binary.

Comment: What sort of information would be useful?

Comment: Port numbers? An example of how those services work?

Comment: These services work by passing a document from one service to another, applying different large operations each time. Port numbers don't really matter, but we'll probably be using ports 5001-5010

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To honor docker's philosophy and take advantage of all the goodies microservices architecture has to offer, you should put each microservice in its own container.

Some of the advantages of microservices architecture:

- Improved fault isolation
- Eliminates long-term commitment to a single technology stack
- Makes it easier for a new developer to understand the functionality
  of a service
- Easier upgrade management
- Improved Security
- Resiliance
- Easier Scaling
- Easier Deployment
- ...

In order to do that, You should first create a user-defined network for your related containers. User-defined networks has internal DNS so you can resolve other containers ip on the same network by name.

Then you need to split your `api_starter` to be microservice specific.

Other tasks to do:

- Specify persistent data path for each microservice (if applies)
- Specify Network ports to expose.

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer! This is a great answer to what I was looking for! Once I turn each individual into its own docker container, would I put a docker compose in the root of the directory?

Comment: Thats correct, You need to create docker-compose file, specify networks, container, Images (you can build on the fly too)

Comment: Awesome! Thanks very much :) do you know of a good guide where I can learn more about doing that?

Comment: Take a look at compose v3 official reference, and try to look at example all over the internet, that is the best way to learn. (also you will notice bad practices amoung them  which will teach you too.

Comment: Each set of Microservices which satisfy a certain functionality reside in the same repo while, that is the norm. But the approach @FarhadFarahi suggests require to have all microservices reside in a single repo?

Comment: @user3434013 You can go with both approaches, You can keep related microservices in the same repo, you just make their own Dockerfile and keep it with them.